# Open a specific outlook message from a web app in vb.net or c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, web, outlook

In a web application I have to provide an email list of the current user's email account similar to the one in the figure.

```
Action   Date           Sender                      Subject 
------  --------------- ------------------------    ------------
view    1/6/21 10.25 AM jhon.doe@abc.com            Red paint
view    1/6/21 12.00 AM Mr. Green                   pink Car
view    1/6/21 3.38 PM  abcdef.1234@aabb.eu         little funny dog
view    1/7/21 12.00 AM europe.america@terra.com    Holiday
```

The list could be filtered by sender or part of the subject or both. When the user clicks on a message it must be opened in outlook.

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook or EWS? where to find some examples in c# or vb.net? TIA

Comment: with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook I got the mail list easily but then how to open the selected message in outlook? How to filter emails?

Comment: Just a question here, what's the end goal here?  Why I'm asking if this is a web app as your title says and depending on your hosting Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook will in all likely hood not be viable.  EWS might be your best bet

Comment: Hi Hursey, I can confirm that it is a web app and that it will be used on a company intranet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code to filter the email and open it in the outlook in the asp.net web app.

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

            Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox =  mapiNameSpace.Folders["Senderemail"].Folders["somefolder"];
            Outlook.MailItem item1 =(Outlook.MailItem) myInbox.Items.Cast<Outlook.MailItem>().Where(i=> (i.Subject == "subjectname") && (i.CreationTime==DateTime.Parse("Dateime"))).FirstOrDefault();
            item1.Display(true);
```

`item.Display(true)` method is used to open the email item in the outlook.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I will try your code as soon as possible.

Comment: i Jack... your code is ok great !! The only change i made is for filtering mail :      
filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " = 'the red paint box'"

mailItemsFiltered = myFolder.Items.Restrict(filter)

Comment: @Ven, I am glad that your problem has been solved. If you don't mind, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Automation of any Office application from a web application is not really a good idea. You can't automate Office applications on the end user machine, all automation will take place on the server server, which is not really what you need I think. Here is what MS states for that:

> Microsoft strongly recommends that developers find alternatives to Automation of Office if they need to develop server-side solutions. Because of the limitations to Office's design, changes to Office configuration are not enough to resolve all issues. Microsoft strongly recommends a number of alternatives that do not require Office to be installed server-side, and that can perform most common tasks more efficiently and more quickly than Automation. Before you involve Office as a server-side component in your project, consider alternatives.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

If you deal with Exchange profiles only in Outlook, you may consider using Exchange Web Services or any other APIs such as Graph API instead. See [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.